# How can I make an image appear in a place and then appear in another location several times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want that when pressing a button, a command is created so that a png disappears after a few seconds, and then it appears in another location, and then in another after a few seconds, and then in another, as if it were moving.
I tried to do it with several def, with sleep and with destroy widget but it still appears all at the same time and I don't know how to put it right.
I think it could be done with "for" but I don't know how to use it yet. Help me please?

```
def destroy_widget(widget):
    widget.destroy()
    
def texto():
    link=tk.StringVar()
    no=tk.Label(ventana,text="Hay algo en el camino...",font=("Times",18,"bold"),anchor='n',width=24, height=3,bg="#137420", fg="#9AD51A",bd=25,relief = "ridge")
    no.place(x=430,y = 400,anchor ='center')
    caja = tk.Entry(ventana,textvariable=link,width=50,state="readonly")
    caja.place(x=430,y = 410,anchor ='center')
    lin="https://www.tumblr.com/blog/mundo000011"
    link.set(lin)

def saliendo():
    canvas.delete(ima)
    ima2 = canvas.create_image(247,780,image=myimg)
    ventana.after(5000, destroy_widget, ima2)
    ima3 = canvas.create_image(247,500,image=myimg)
    ventana.after(5000, destroy_widget, ima3)
    texto()



def salir():

    if trad["text"]=="ar.ab.iz.":
        
        trad.config(text=leta)
        saliendo()

ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

myimg = tk.PhotoImage(file='circlo.png')
posx=70
posy=235
ima = canvas.create_image(78,235,image=myimg)

boton2 = tk.Button(text="  Ir  ",font=("Verdana",16), command=salir)
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=746,y=379)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

Image is this:

[image]

Main widgets and variables are initialized:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root=Tk()
width1=900
height1=200
root.geometry(f"{width1}x{height1}+10+10")
random_x=0
random_y=0
```

Then, we will create 2 functions:

```
def create_image(j):
    if j!=0: #=== If j is not 0
        x=random.randint(0,size1)
        y=random.randint(0,size2)

        image_lbl.place_forget() #=== Forget the placement of the widget
        image_lbl.place(x=x,y=y)
        root.after(1000,lambda: create_image(j-1)) #=== Go to the function with value of j as 1 less than the previous 
    
        
def hello():
    j=random.randint(0,10) #=== Random integer from 0 to 10
    root.after(1000,lambda: create_image(j)) #=== Lambda is used to pass arguments in the function
```

The last part. It contains the images, the width and button

```
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"path/to/icon.png")
image1=Image.open(r"path/to/icon.png")
width=image1.size[0]
height=image1.size[1]
image_lbl=Label(root,image=image)
size1=width1-width
size2=height1-height
image_lbl.place(x=random_x,y=random_y)
Button(root,text="Change Position",command=hello).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Whole code

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root=Tk()
width1=900
height1=200
root.geometry(f"{width1}x{height1}+10+10")
random_x=0
random_y=0
def create_image(j):
    if j!=0:
        x=random.randint(0,size1)
        y=random.randint(0,size2)

        image_lbl.place_forget()
        image_lbl.place(x=x,y=y)
        root.after(1000,lambda: create_image(j-1))
    
        
def hello():
    j=random.randint(0,10)
    print(j)
    root.after(1000,lambda: create_image(j))
        
        
image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"path/to/icon.png")
image1=Image.open(r"path/to/icon.png")
width=image1.size[0]
height=image1.size[1]
image_lbl=Label(root,image=image)
size1=width1-width
size2=height1-height
image_lbl.place(x=random_x,y=random_y)
Button(root,text="Change Position",command=hello).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but with that how can I choose the locations where it will appear again?